# using DTO with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, dto

I have a EFM which is mapped with a POCO Entity, and m using WCF for business logic

while calling this function in the WCF :-

```
 public  List<DTO.Product> Viewall()
    {
        var val= _repositoryprod.GetAll().Take(2).ToList();
        return val;
    }
```

i get an error **The socket connection has been disposed.**

I tried **serializing** the DTO class and even using  **[DataContract]** and **[DataMember]** attribute but no luck.

M using TCP Binding and just max every value still why its showing socket connection disposed.....

> binding name="netTcpStreaming" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967296"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" closeTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" maxConnections="100" listenBacklog="100"

What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Enable tracing and check if you can find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, as with EFM + POCO u need to add the ApplyDataContractResolver attribute in the WCF Operation Contracts

Just follow this walkthrough and you are done

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705457.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The error can be caused because of the default limit for maxItemsInObjectGraph is 65536. Try changing that and retry!

Comment: well tried that also have set maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"

Comment: @Ankit this configuration should be set on both client and server endpoints

Comment: Then, you should first enable the tracing to get more information  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx

Comment: Also, check if you are using any 'using' block which is explicitly disposing the connection

Comment: @Boomer ok der seems to be some problem during serialization i have a few types like decimal, short, nullable int, bool and string. Is any of des creating an issue

Comment: @Ankit the best way to know is to enable tracing

Comment: Nullable types are not serializable as they are of the type Nullable<T> with a default Generic Argument (of type T) in constructor

Comment: @Punit i guess Nullable types are serializable as mentioned in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx

Comment: @Boomer well have enabled tracing and that where i find the error is happening during serialization... just came across this

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/05/poco-proxies-part-2-serializing-poco-proxies.aspx 

As m using Poco Entity so serializing wont work by just adding the attribute, will have to do manual work..DAmn :X